# Rails Client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my site, I want to use different validation ( for example - in my registration page - I use client side validation, but in my posts page - I use standard validation =>

```
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
               <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

but when I submit my empty form - I saw standard validation and client-side validation[image]

It itself adds "can't be blank"  ( in my picture - under the field with title and text )

I think that makes  `config/initializers/client_side_validation.rb` :

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

How can I turn off it, only to this form?

Answer (score 0):

i think ur script for client side validation is not working cause the form is getting submitted. If u want a form not be be validated on the client side, ':validate' param to false in ur form.

```
<%= book.fields_for :pages, :validate => false do |page| -%>
```

Comment: no, it was my first idea, but when i click in fields - nothing change... but when i submit form - then created this <label> with "can't be blank msg"